# Поймать исключение из Task в основном коде программы

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, многопоточность, tpl

Как пробросить исключение из Task в основной поток WinForms приложения?

Сценарий: Есть кнопка, эта кнопка создает задачу, которая выполняет некоторый код в фоне, в задаче возникает необрабатываемое исключение, а основная программа должна узнать об этом.

Читал MSDN и там предлагали следующее:

1) Ставить Task.Wait, но в этом случае мой UI заморозится.

2)Чекать статус Task. Но где его лучше чекать и с какой переодичностью?

Никаких событий у Task я не нашел.

Answer (score 3):

Подписаться на "событие" можно с помощью метода [`ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
```

Советую также изучить использование ключевых слов `async` и `await` - они многое упрощают.

Если вы используете библиотеки для ведения логов, то посмотрите нет ли там нужного вам метода. К примеру, если вы используете NLog и вам надо вывести асинхронную ошибку в лог - можно воспользоваться методом [`Logger.SwallowAsync`](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.0.0/html/M_NLog_Logger_SwallowAsync.htm)

Comment: Стоит уточнить, что эта конструкция должна выполняется в UI-потоке. Иначе нужно будет явно передать в `ContinueWith()` нужный task scheduler. Для консоли, конечно, неактуально, но автор спрашивал про WinForms.

Comment: Здравствуйте. А если я все же использую консоль и логи просто записываю в файл, так как мне кажется NLog приписывать очень неоправданно.  `try
                {
                        Task.Run(() =>Method());
                }
                catch (ThreadAbortException)
                {
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    Log.Write(error);
                }`